# Mail app and exchange server

Tags: applications, email, exchange, attachments

I am using Moto G and accessing my office mail on native Mail app synced with MS Exchange Server. Whenever I am forwarding a mail, the app downloads the entire attachments and the mail is only sent after that. My earlier HTC phone with similar setup used to do this without downloading the attachment, but the receiver would gett the mail with attachments. Am I missing some particular setting here? How can I make my Moto G to send the forwards without downloading entire attachments?